# what to do when my repository is deleted and in the project it cant find it in unity? Unity version control

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, lts

This is the error in the project when I try to check in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzIoD.png)

And in the App version control:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5uLa.png)

If you need more info to help me feel free to say it!
Please help me because I am stuck at this for a long time and I can't collab with my friend.

Comment: well, if it is deleted it, is.  you wont be able to share it with your friend. However, much as I havent used unitys version control, you can probably make a new one in its current state

Comment: How can I make a new one in the same unity project?

Comment: I dont use unitys source control, so Id say read up on their documentation